# Request dentro de función que pertenece a otra función Laravel Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax, requests

Hola estoy tratando de utilizar Request dentro de una consulta la cual tiene una función, y todo esto está dentro de otra función. No tengo idea cómo hacerlo ya que me sale un error que no reconoce al request.

Adjunto mi Ajax, donde envío los parámetros:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-add', function() {
        altair_helpers.content_preloader_show('md');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ URL::to('authorization-factura-proveedor') }}',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'function': 'Agregar_bill',
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success == 'true'){
                    UIkit.modal("#addModal").show();
                    altair_helpers.content_preloader_hide('md');
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                if (data.status == 401){
                    swal(
                      'Error!',
                      'Usuario No Autorizado!',
                      'error'
                    );
                    altair_helpers.content_preloader_hide('md');
                }
            },
        });


    });
```

Y adjunto la función donde me sale el error de no reconocer a la variable "$request":

```
public function authorization(Request $request){

    if(User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->whereHas('permissions', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereName($request->function);
        })->count()){

        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'true',
        ], 200);

    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'false',
            'errors'  => 'Acceso No Autorizado!',
        ], 401);
    }

}
```

El error es el siguiente:

> {message: "Undefined variable: request", exception: "ErrorException",…}
>   message: "Undefined variable: request"
>   exception: "ErrorException"
>   file: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gastosFR\app\Http\Controllers\Contabilidad\BillController.php"
>   line: 39

Comment: Por favor se tan amable de editar y colocar tu código como texto así como agregar el error que obtienes

Comment: Ya lo actualicé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que `$request` está definida en otro ámbito que el de la función en que la estás usando. Te paso unos ejemplos de la documentación de PHP.

[Funciones anónimas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)
...
Las funciones anónimas (cierres) pueden heredar variables del ámbito padre. Cualquier variable debe ser pasada al constructor de lenguaje `use`.

**Ejemplo #3 Heredar variables de un ámbito padre**

```
$mensaje = 'hola';

// Sin "use"
$ejemplo = function () {
    var_dump($mensaje);
};
$ejemplo();

// Heredar $mensaje
$ejemplo = function () use ($mensaje) {
    var_dump($mensaje);
};
$ejemplo();

// El valor de la variable heredada está cuando la función
// está definida, no cuando se le invoca
$mensaje = 'mundo';
$ejemplo();

// Reiniciar el mensaje
$mensaje = 'hola';

// Heredar por referencia
$ejemplo = function () use (&$mensaje) {
    var_dump($mensaje);
};
$ejemplo();

// El valor cambiado en el ámbito padre
// se refleja dentro de la llamada a la función
$mensaje = 'mundo';
$ejemplo();

// Los cierres también aceptan argumentos normales
$ejemplo = function ($arg) use ($mensaje) {
    var_dump($arg . ' ' . $mensaje);
};
$ejemplo("hola");
```

Lo que para tu código, se traduce en pasar la variable `$request`, a la función anónima en la que quieres usarla:

```
User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereHas('permissions', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereName($request->function);
    })
    ->count();
```