# ¿Cómo obtener variables de una función y enviarles a otra función que se encuentra dentro del mismo Controller?

Tags: laravel, funciones, variables, controller

Tengo dos Funciones la primera es la del Index que recibe parámetros de un formulario para ejecutar las consultas y devolver la vista. Necesito Utilizar estas variables en otra función llamada excel para poder exportar a Excel esa consulta. las variables son (query,quer,que,inicio) a la función excel():

```
    class UpsetController extends Controller
    {
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    protected function index(Request $request)
    {
    if($request)
    {
    $anio=date("Y");
    $inicio="$anio-01-01";
    $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
    $que=trim($request->get('searchTe'));
    $quer=trim($request->get('searchTex'));
    $ex=trim($request->get('exportar'));
    $upset=DB::table('externos')
    ->select(DB::raw('fecha_iniI, id_cajero, COUNT(id_incidente) AS cantidad, CASE WHEN(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))) IS NULL THEN "EN PROCESO" ELSE concat(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))," Minutos") END AS OFFLINE,CASE WHEN ((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)) IS NULL THEN "INCIDENTE ABIERTO" ELSE concat((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)," %") END AS UPS'))
    ->whereBetween('fecha_iniI', [$inicio, $quer])
    ->groupBy('id_cajero')
    ->orderBy('UPS','asc')
    ->paginate(10);
    return view('modulos.upset.index',["upset"=>$upset,"upse"=>$upse,"searchText"=>$query,"searchTe"=>$que,"searchTex"=>$quer]);
        }
    }
    public function excel()
    {
        Excel::create('UPTIME', function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('UPTIME', function($sheet) {
                $upset = Upset::select(DB::raw('fecha_iniI, id_cajero, COUNT(id_incidente) AS cantidad, CASE WHEN(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))) IS NULL THEN "EN PROCESO" ELSE concat(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))," Minutos") END AS OFFLINE,CASE WHEN ((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)) IS NULL THEN "100 %" ELSE concat((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)," %") END AS UPS'))
                ->whereBetween('fecha_iniI', [$que, $quer])
            ->groupBy('id_cajero')
            ->get();
                $sheet->row(1,['Fecha Primer Incidente','Codigo Cajero','Numero de Incidentes','TIEMPO OFFLINE EN MINUTOS','UPSET ANUAL',]);
                foreach($upset as $index=>$upset)
                {
                $sheet->row($index+2,[
                $upset->fecha_iniI,
                $upset->id_cajero,
                $upset->cantidad,
                $upset->OFFLINE,
                $upset->UPS,
                ]); 
                }               
            });
        })->export('xls');
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes llamar a otra función en la misma clase con `$this->nombreDeLaFuncion()`. Para pasarle parámetros, debes declararlos en la función para que los reciba `public function excel($param1, $param2)`, y se los pasas cuando la invocas `$this->excel($param1,$param2)`

Comment: perdon que les quite su tiempo, la verdad soy muy novato entiendo que mi funcion excel la dejo de esta forma:

public function excel($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
{
      $this->index($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)//quiero recibir esos parametros de la funcion index
}

Comment: Creo que sería al revés. La función `index(Request $request)` recibe los datos del formulario en el Request, y tú asignas algunos de esos datos a las variables `$query`, `$quer`, `$que` e `$inicio`. Luego se los puedes pasar a la otra función así `$this->excel($query, $quer, $que, $inicio)`. Teniendo en cuenta que debes declarar esos parámetros que recibe `excel()`, por ej `public function excel($query, $quer, $que, $inicio)`. Luego dentro de `excel()` haces algo con esos parámetros, no sé que es lo que hace esa función, pero veo que no tiene return. Cual sería la responsabilidad de `excel()`?

Comment: para utilizar los parametros dentro de mi funcion excel solo los utilizo con el mismo nombre no? por ejemplo: public function excel($query, $quer)
{ ->whereBetween('fecha_iniI', [$query, $quer]) }

Comment: Sí, si los declaras de esa forma, van a ser variables dentro del ámbito de la función excel, tomarán los valores que le pases al llamar la función, y las puedes usar como cualquier variable

Comment: Como veo que dentro de excel(), quieres usar las variables dentro de otra función "hija", puedes darle una mirada a [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/321964/92278) para ver cómo usar una variable de la funcion "padre" dentro de una función "hija". Algo así `Excel::create('UPTIME', function($excel) use($query, $quer) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 formas:

La primera forma es llamando a la función mediante `$this->nombreFuncion(parametro1, parametro2)`, ya que $this representa la clase/modelo en el que estás trabajando y que está instanciado (importante).

La segunda forma es utilizando Eloquent, y es `self::nombreFuncion(parametro1, parametro2)`.

Finalmente, recuerda que la función tiene que estar preparada para recibir los 2 parámetros.

Utiliza la que más te convenga